# matrix transpose template

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

When I try to write a code for matrix transpose using template I have this following error.

> Error 1   error C2248: 'Matrix::elements' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Matrix'

Can anyone give me how to fix this error?

```
//Matrix.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T, int m, int n>
class Matrix;


template<class T, int m, int n>
class Matrix
{
vector<vector<T>> elements;
int nrow;
int ncol;

public:
Matrix();
~Matrix();
void print();

Matrix<T, n, m> transpose();

};

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n>::Matrix() : nrow(m), ncol(n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++){
    vector<T> row(ncol, i);
    elements.push_back(row);
}
}

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n>::~Matrix(){}

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, n, m> Matrix<T, m, n>::transpose(){
Matrix<T, n, m> m;
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j){
        m.elements[j][i] = elements[i][j];
    }
}
return m;
}

template<class T, int m, int n>
void Matrix<T, m, n>::print()
{
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
    {
        cout << elements[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

//main.cpp

#include "Matrix.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Matrix<int, 3, 2> a;
Matrix<int, 3, 2> b;
Matrix<int, 2, 3> c;
c = a.transpose();
c.print();
}
```

Comment: You are using `m` for both the template parameter and the variable. Make them different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matrix<T, n, m>` and `Matrix<T, m, n>` are different classes at all when `m != n`. It means you couldn't access the private member of `Matrix<T, n, m>` in the member function of `Matrix<T, m, n>`.

You might add friend declaration to solve the issue:

```
template<class T, int m, int n>
class Matrix
{

    vector<vector<T>> elements;
    int nrow;
    int ncol;

    public:
    Matrix();
    ~Matrix();
    void print();

    Matrix<T, n, m> transpose();

    friend class Matrix<T, n, m>;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Matrix<T, m, n>` and `Matrix<T, n, m>` are different classes when `m` and `n` are not the same. One cannot access the `private` members of the other. You can avoid the access problems by providing `public` member functions that provide access to the `private` member variables.

You won't notice the problem if `m` and `n` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the following function in your code:

```
template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, n, m> Matrix<T, m, n>::transpose() {
    Matrix<T, n, m> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j) {
            m.elements[j][i] = elements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

The reason for the error is that you are creating a new Matrix `m`. In this Matrix elements is a private variable and hence you can not access it. I would suggest either creating a public getter function to return a pointer to elements or making elements a public variable (but that may not be good style as it doesn't encapsulate the data).

Your getter function can be a simple:

```
vector<vector<T> >* get_elements_ptr() {
    return &elements;
}
```

Your problematic function should then look something like:

```
template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, n, m> Matrix<T, m, n>::transpose() {
    Matrix<T, n, m> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j) {
            m.get_elements_ptr()->at(j)[i] = elements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

This will fix your issue. However, on a side note I think your project design can be tweaked a bit altogether to totally avoid having a Matrix inside another Matrix object. Have you considered having a pointer to a dynamically allocated Matrix instead? This will reduce the amount of copying your program does tremendously and will improve both the memory and run-time efficiency of your program greatly.

Hope this helps!